# How can I make layout like this in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three column 5-5-2 and it should be same height but middle column has two rows,first row is a single column, and second row has two column

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row equal">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">    
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-sm-12">
          <figure>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x150" alt="">    
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-sm-6">
          <figure>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <figure>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x600" alt="">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bootstrap and set the img size.
Here is code:

```
 <figure class="figure">
      <img src="..." width="200px" height="200px" class="figure-img img-fluid img-rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
      <figcaption class="figure-caption">A caption for the above image.</figcaption>
    </figure>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific with your answer. Share your code